# Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm) - Flutter Crash

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, maps

My Flutter app is crashing on loading

It operates a FutureBuilder and I believe this to be where the issue comes from.

My app makes an API Call and returns the data to a map marker.

When i have the FutureBuilder return a list view it works fine.

However, when i change it to return a Stack containing my Map SDK and the buttons to call the API it crashes on start up.

Relevant code is below, thank you!

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget { 

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
 

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<Stations> stations;
  BuildContext _context;
  MapMarkerExample _mapMarkerExample; 
  


  @override
  void initState() {
   stations = API_Call().fetchStations(); 
   super.initState();
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Example 1'),
        ),
        
      body: Container(
 
        child: FutureBuilder<Stations>(
          future: stations,
       
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
     
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Error");
        }
  
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return 
          
          Stack(
          children: [
            HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
          

            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    button('Stations Near Me', _anchoredMapMarkersButtonClicked),
                    button('Clear', _clearButtonClicked),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
            );
        }
        
        return Text("Loading");
           
           

            }
        ) 
      )
        );
           }
```

api_call.dart

```
class API_Call {

Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();

      final response = await client.get(
      'https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=x,-x&return=transport&apiKey=API_KEY');
   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Stations.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); 
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load stations');
  }
    }
    }
```

api_manager.dart

```
 typedef ShowDialogFunction = void Function(String title, String message);

 class MapMarkerExample{
 
    
  void showAnchoredMapMarkers() { 
  print('step5');
  
   GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = _callGeoCoordinates();
           // use the coords .. to add a marker
           _addCircleMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 0);
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
           print('step6');
  } 

    
 GeoCoordinates _callGeoCoordinates() {
   print('step7');
   var stations;

   Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
       stations = await API_Call().fetchStations(); 
       for (Station stations in stations) {
           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
           // use the coords .. to add a marker
           _addCircleMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 0);
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
           } 
        }
    }


  HereMapController _hereMapController;
  List<MapMarker> _mapMarkerList = [];
  MapImage _poiMapImage;
  MapImage _circleMapImage;
  ShowDialogFunction _showDialog;
  List<MapMarker3D> _mapMarker3DList = [];
   
   MapMarkerExample(ShowDialogFunction showDialogCallback, HereMapController hereMapController) {
    _showDialog = showDialogCallback;
    _hereMapController = hereMapController;

    double distanceToEarthInMeters = 8000;
    _hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithDistance(
      GeoCoordinates(x, -x), distanceToEarthInMeters);

    // Setting a tap handler to pick markers from map.
    _setTapGestureHandler();

    _showDialog("Note", "Tap markers for more.");
    }




  void clearMap() {
    for (var mapMarker in _mapMarkerList) {
      _hereMapController.mapScene.removeMapMarker(mapMarker);
    }
    _mapMarkerList.clear();

    for (var mapMarker3D in _mapMarker3DList) {
      _hereMapController.mapScene.removeMapMarker3d(mapMarker3D);
    }
    _mapMarker3DList.clear();
  }

  Future<void> _addPOIMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, int drawOrder) async {
    // Reuse existing MapImage for new map markers.
    if (_poiMapImage == null) {
      Uint8List imagePixelData = await _loadFileAsUint8List('assets/poi.png');
      _poiMapImage = MapImage.withPixelDataAndImageFormat(imagePixelData, ImageFormat.png);
    }

    Anchor2D anchor2D = Anchor2D.withHorizontalAndVertical(0.5, 1);

    MapMarker mapMarker = MapMarker.withAnchor(geoCoordinates, _poiMapImage, anchor2D);
    mapMarker.drawOrder = drawOrder;

    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.setString("key_poi", "Next Departures");
    mapMarker.metadata = metadata;

    _hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    _mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);
  }

  Future<void> _addCircleMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, int drawOrder) async {
    // Reuse existing MapImage for new map markers.
    if (_circleMapImage == null) {
      Uint8List imagePixelData = await _loadFileAsUint8List('assets/circle.png');
      _circleMapImage = MapImage.withPixelDataAndImageFormat(imagePixelData, ImageFormat.png);
    }
    
    MapMarker mapMarker = MapMarker(geoCoordinates, _circleMapImage);
    mapMarker.drawOrder = drawOrder;

    _hereMapController.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    _mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _loadFileAsUint8List(String assetPathToFile) async {
    // The path refers to the assets directory as specified in pubspec.yaml.
    ByteData fileData = await rootBundle.load(assetPathToFile);
    return Uint8List.view(fileData.buffer);
  }

  void _setTapGestureHandler() {
    _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener = TapListener.fromLambdas(lambda_onTap: (Point2D touchPoint) {
      _pickMapMarker(touchPoint);
    });
  }

  void _pickMapMarker(Point2D touchPoint) {
    double radiusInPixel = 2;
    _hereMapController.pickMapItems(touchPoint, radiusInPixel, (pickMapItemsResult) {
      // Note that 3D map markers can't be picked yet. Only marker, polgon and polyline map items are pickable.
      List<MapMarker> mapMarkerList = pickMapItemsResult.markers;
      if (mapMarkerList.length == 0) {
        print("No map markers found.");
        return;
      }
    });
  }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add your Google maps api key on iOS? This is most likely the reason for your crash.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad It is not Google Maps, it is HERE Maps. I actaully had removed the API KEY for privacy - the API Key is fully entered in my project

Comment: I don't mean the API key to make calls, but the key is also needed to render the map, and that key is added via XCODE, to info.plist. What is the output of `flutter run -v`? It should display a verbose output, of what exactly is causing the crash. If you can add that to your post, it'd help.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad My info.plist & Android build.gradle both have my API keys entered. Do I run ```flutter run -v``` from terminal after i attempt to run app? It's currently displaying lots of lines of feedback. Thank you

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Have added feedback

Comment: What is before `end of dumpstacktrace`? There's something saying map_marker future not complete. Please share what's before this.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Have added more data - over 1000 lines returned so will add the rest of data isn't in there, don't want to add too much irrelevant data

Answer (score 1):

In `api_manager.dart`, this looks very suspicous, and you aren't returning anything from this function, it could also explain the error saying `future not complete`

```
 Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
   stations = await API_Call().fetchStations(); 
   
       for (Station stations in stations) {
           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
           // use the coords .. to add a marker
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
           }   

          // GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = stations.coordinates;
          // _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
 
    }
 }
```

You have to return a `Stations` object from it, try after your for loop something like `return stations;`, it could fix your problem, if the error changes, it's also a good start.

Also change your line in future builder to this:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)
```

And for the meantime, remove this `_setTapGestureHandler()`. The crash is most likely caused by some memory leak, and from the code posted, it could be explained by `listeners`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I tried adding it in after my ```for{}``` but still returned ```future not complete``` in my search. I have a ```return stations``` in my ```api_call.dart```,  the for loop is just to add the POI marker with the lat/lon pulled

Comment: Run your app in debug mode, and notice where it crashes\sets a breakpoint. Then gradually step into the breakpoint.

Comment: I added info to my answer which could narrow things down, give it a try.

Comment: Could the fact my ```Future``` is calling inside a ```void``` be causing the issue of ```Future``` still not returning?

Comment: Possibly, have you tried the steps I added to the answer? We have to know what is causing it to crash exactly, then we can fix the one

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have implemented your steps and made a couple of changes myself. The app is crashing as soon as it gets to loading the map. It is now freezing on the loading screen and not progressing to load the map. So as the map is depending on ```Future``` loading, perhaps my call just isn't completed? Is there anything in my call that your experience tells you isn't correct? Have posted my updated ```API_Manager```at bottom of my post, with the call now part of it

Comment: If you aren't experienced with breakpoints, you can use the old-fashioned `print` method. This isn't advisable in general for practice, but it'll help figure out what is going on. In the beginning of every function, use a print statement `print('step1')` and before the return `print('step2')`, for the function that comes after this one, use `print('step3')` and then step4..etc, see how far the printing goes. For example, if you reach the print(step5), you know it's not crashing before this point. If you have 5 functions, you'll use 10 print statments, one at the beginning and one at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your clear instructions, I had tried a similar technique earlier, but not installing a ```print``` at the end of the function! I have returns up until the contents of ```void showAnchoredMapMarkers()```, within the ```UPDATE API_Manager```. It then returns ```[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port```. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome, is everything okay now?

Comment: I have tracked issue to my UPDATED API_Manager, have posted my print return above, returns up to ```Print 3``` but not ```Print 4```. Therefore the issue must be within the ```void``` in which I am calling and placing the lat/lon?  Am I extracting the ```coordinates``` in the correct way? I have looked online but can't seem to figure out my sequence

Comment: My first fetchStations (before ```async```) in ```API_Manager.dart``` is blue underlined with ```The declaration 'fetchStations' isn't referenced.``` as the feedback, could this be the issue? I have tried editing it around

Comment: IF you aren't printing step4, that means that hasData is returning false, meaning your API isn't returning data. Remove the `&& hasData`, it should print step4, but don't know still what will come out after it. Double check your API key, or your query parameters, and update me what happens, this is fun and interesting.

Comment: Update - I have implemented a```print(snapshot);``` to see what is being returned. This is the feedback ```flutter: step1
flutter: AsyncSnapshot<Stations>(ConnectionState.none, null, null)
flutter: step2
flutter: step3``` I have double checked and the URL w/API returns fine in a web browser. As the connection state is ```null```, does that mean the ```get```  just isn't calling? Thanks again

Comment: `"ConnectionState.none"` ?? Are you connected to the internet? This all boils down to one thing, your API isn't returning data, and it's not a flutter problem. This is something specific to this API, check the API key, the link, the parameters, and most importantly, being connected to the internet.

Comment: I have just swapped in a ```List.view``` to check and it is returning the list fine in a basic text page format. That makes me feel that the API call is working, but its the actual ```Future``` for the ```Void``` and map marker itself that is returning none?

Comment: the future is returning null, [check here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html)

Comment: Have made some progress recently - current status is ```flutter: step1
flutter: AsyncSnapshot<Stations>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
flutter: step2
flutter: step3
flutter: AsyncSnapshot<Stations>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of 'Stations', null)
flutter: step2
flutter: step3
flutter: step4
``` and then it crashes when it returns the Stack, am looking into the Stack now to see if it is causing issues, as well as the Void, as they both come at the same time!

Comment: Have updated API_Manager in original post to reflect current status, which is now returning ```connection.done```, however Future is still not complete

Comment: I think I have the problem! It ```prints``` up until I load the stack, when I ```//``` cancel out the buttons it still crashes, but when i cancel out the ```//HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated)``` it no longer crashes and the emulator just loads the buttons fine

Comment: Awesome, I couldn't find the `_onMapcreated` in your code

Comment: I had to add ```SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);``` to my ```void main```, the map and app is now loading fine. I am now onto the next step of making the button work, it is now returning the error ```Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: latitude)```

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS haha. Your new error is easy. Just double check your json response and how you are accessing latitude

Comment: Getting there, thank you! Have cleared that error now and am now recieving ```The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator``` Do I need to return the listview builder in my ```homepage.dart``` even though I am not displaying it?

Comment: I think it's time to close this post and mark it as answered. Opening a new post with code directly related the current problem would be easier to debug. You're most welcome!